# Xcode 11.5 - This app could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode started displaying this message **every second time I run my project in the simulator** after deleting the app from it. So I am having to delete the app from the simulator every build.

I've already cleaned the **DerivedData folder**, checked my **bundle version**, **erased all the settings from the simulator**, uninstalled and **installed all pods again**, and **nothing** works. I don't know what more can I do to solve it.

Here is the full error message from Xcode:

Could not install at this time.
Could not hardlink copy /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1258F538-0C25-4805-9721-0135291047D4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E81BC1DF-2E6B-4F4C-810F-FA45731DB58F/Alerta Câmbio.app to /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1258F538-0C25-4805-9721-0135291047D4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.q9B8Po/extracted/Payload/Alerta Câmbio.app with manifest /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1258F538-0C25-4805-9721-0135291047D4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.q9B8Po/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.com.CurrencyChecker